# match a pattern and extract next 10 characters perl

Tags: string, perl, pattern-matching

I want a perl regular expression which can match the pattern `LOC_` from a string and extract the next 10 characters including LOC_ from the string.

**example:**

- string : H2CTT5_ORYRU|LOC_Os02g10100
  result : LOC_Os02g10100
- string: Os02g0528200|LOC_Os02g32660
  result: LOC_Os02g32660
- string: LOC_Os09g54663|Os02g0528200|H2CTT6_OCYRU
  result: LOC_Os09g54663

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
if ($str=~ /(LOC_.{10})/) {
    print "'$1'\n";
}
```

(I think question must be a duplicate or at least the answer could be found easily from the Perl regex documentation, see for example

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Matching-repetitions )

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for the regex. This one works better for a 5 five field file where this field is the fifth one. So I used this inside a perl script for splitting up each line and using this regex on the fifth field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 foreach (<DATA>){
    m/(LOC_).{10}/g;
    print "$&\n";
 }

__DATA__
string : H2CTT5_ORYRU|LOC_Os02g10100
result : LOC_Os02g10100
string: Os02g0528200|LOC_Os02g32660
result: LOC_Os02g32660
string: LOC_Os09g54663|Os02g0528200|H2CTT6_OCYRU
result: LOC_Os09g54663
```